# jQuery animate bug with col in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation, css-tables

It seems that animating a col width to 0 is broken in Chrome (Linux) by using jQuery (other browsers seems to work fine). See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/B9mHg/) (just click the red box).

Do you know a workaround? Setting width to the TDs and animating those is not an option as our columns are quite large.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the question is almost a year old but the solution to this problem is applying a width for the td element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B9mHg/55/